# Reference to AudioVideoPlayback namespace

Tags: c#, video, reference, directx

Disclaimer: I am a beginner and it is showing.

I am trying to follow the instructions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/53d1071b-26d9-406a-877c-3b33eedf8a4c/) to play a movie within a c# program.

I have downloaded and installed:

- the June 2010 [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6812)
- the [DirectX End-User Runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8109) (June 2010)

Yet when I try to add a reference in my c# project to `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback` I cannot find it.

Here is what I am doing: On the menu bar I click *Project | Add Reference*. Then I search through the COM components for something that is similar to "Microsoft Direct X AudioVideoPlayback" but I can't see anything remotely close.

Am I missing something? Did I incorrectly install the SDK?

Thanks,

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to browse for it.  The assembly is in [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)

> %WinDir%\assembly\ GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
>
> On the menu bar I click Project | Add Reference | **Browse**

Comment: Thanks, this sort of solves the problem but now when I start debugging (f5) the program crashes. Any ideas? A possible clue is that when I publish and then install the program it runs okay. Also all other directx programs work okay.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?  Maybe you can post another question with some code and exception  you are getting

Comment: Sorry no messages, it just hangs. I have found a work around - I am no longer using directx. It appears directx is obsolete.